# View HTML page use javascript

Tags: javascript

excuse me for my English.
I want to display html content on other Web addresses,
Until recently I use this PHP code

```
<? php readfile ("http://stresne-krytiny.eu/vysuvacie_menu/")?>
```

The next site I can not use PHP, Please advise how to view the contents via javascript.

I thank everyone for their answers

Comment: `<?`  and `php` cant have spaces in between.

Comment: just stick it in an `iframe`?

Comment: You could use an iframe or jQuery's get / ajax function.

Comment: The content of the site has also enabled and it's pop-up menu, via the iframe is bad

Comment: Is the page you're trying to get on the same domain as your own page? If not, you probably can't do it with JavaScript (check [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)).

Comment: I do not know how can I display using jquery

Comment: There is no ,then act as scripts such as Zoppin?

Comment: If this was reply to me, jQuery is written in JavaScript and it has the same limitation I've mentioned above. I don't know what's a Zoppin.

Comment: it is a script that displays live chat for e-shops and the like.

Comment: Then it works with some site that explicitly allows such requests. You cannot do that with any site. Read the link about SOP I gave you above.